# erlang SSHA ldap

Tags: erlang, ldap, sha1

Given a LDAP password stored in SHA-1/{SSHA} how would I validate it in erlang.

For example - given the following {SSHA}:

```
% slappasswd -s myPassword
{SSHA}GEH5kMEQZHYHS95dgr6KmFdg0a4BicBP
%
```

How would I (in erlang) validate that clear text 'myPassword' matches with the hashed value of '{SSHA}GEH5kMEQZHYHS95dgr6KmFdg0a4BicBP'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help from others I've come up with a routine to do this in Erlang.  Following up here to share with others.

First - this link (found in another post) gives functions in other languages doing what I wanted:

- http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html

The trick was that the 'ldap {SSHA}' encoding is a salted-SHA1 hash which is also base64 encoded.  So - you must decode it, extract the salt and then use that in the re-encoding of the 'clear password' for comparison.

Here is a short Erlang routine which does this:

```
validatessha(ClearPassword, SshaHash) ->
    D64 = base64:decode(lists:nthtail(6, SshaHash)),
    {HashedData, Salt} = lists:split(20, binary_to_list(D64)),
    NewHash = crypto:sha(list_to_binary(ClearPassword ++ Salt)),
    string:equal(binary_to_list(NewHash), HashedData).
```

Given the data in my original post - here's the output:

```
67> run:validatessha("myPassword", "{SSHA}GEH5kMEQZHYHS95dgr6KmFdg0a4BicBP").
true
68>
```

Thanx all.

*Mike*

Answer (score 1):

Passwords stored in a directory server are validated using the [BIND](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.2) operation. A properly configured and secured directory server will not allow access to password data; therefore LDAP clients must not be coded expecting that the password data is available, whether encrypted or hashed. LDAP clients must use the BIND operation to validate passwords.

Comment: Understood - we are looking to validate these ssha encrypted passwords outside of ldap - hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

My erlang is very rusty, so this isn't very pretty, but maybe it gets my idea along anyway.

```
run() ->
  Password = "myPassword",
  HashRaw = os:cmd("slappasswd -s " ++ Password),
  Hash1 = lists:nthtail(6, HashRaw),
  Hash2 = lists:concat ([integer_to_list(X, 16) || X <- binary_to_list(crypto:sha(Password))]),
  string:equal(string:to_lower(Hash1), 
               string:to_lower(Hash2)).
```

My idea is that you:

- Run the command whose output you are interested in verifying (slappasswd), save the output and trim away the extra decoration preceding the hash.
- Run `crypto:sha()` from the erlang libraries. Take the binary output from this, and convert it to a list of integers, each of which you then convert to a hexadecimal string, which you then concatenate, thereby create Hash2.
- Compare the output of your command to the output of `crypto:sha()`

EDIT: I don't have this command you're using, so I couldn't really try this very thoroughly.. But it works for `sha1sum`. I hope they are the same!